# CSS attribute selector Modernizr support?

Tags: css, modernizr

Modernizr's documentation is not very clear on this. Does it **support Attribute Selectors**?

```
input[type=name]{
   color:#f00;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a discussion still open on their official Github, so it is still not supported.

https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/pull/649